# Determining if a column has content that consists of multiple row and creating table columns dynamically

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to create columns of a table as many times as there are contents in certain columns of a sql table and then fill these columns with content in t the same manner. The code below is used to determine which columns are not empty and thereby adding a extra value to `$n` that will be used to make columns `$n` times.

Although only the first four columns have content, the code below is adding to `$n` as if there is content in the empty columns. How can I check if an entire column with possibly multiple rows have content or not?

```
$query = "
SELECT * 
  FROM analysis_database a
  JOIN microbiology_analysis_database m
    ON a.m_analysis_id = m.id 
 WHERE order_id = $order_id 
   AND a.analysis_type = 'Microbiological' 
   AND m.analysis_type = 'Microbiological';
";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$n = 0;
if (!is_null($fetch['step_1'])) {
    $n++;
} 
if (!is_null($fetch['step_2'])) {
    $n++;
} 
if (!is_null($fetch['step_3'])) {
    $n++;
} 
if (!is_null($fetch['step_4'])) {
    $n++;
} 
if (!is_null($fetch['step_5'])) {
    $n++;
} 
if (!is_null($fetch['step_6'])) {
    $n++;
} 
if (!is_null($fetch['step_7'])) {
    $n++;
} 
if (!is_null($fetch['step_8'])) {
    $n++;
} 
if (!is_null($fetch['step_9'])) {
    $n++;
}
```

This part is used to make the table headers dynamically:

```
for ($k = 1 ; $k < $n; $k++) { 
    $output .= '<th>Step '.$k.'</th>';
}
```

And this is for the content of the corresponding header:

```
for ($k = 1 ; $k < $n; $k++) { 
    <td>Column Content</td>;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for a higher step to be filled in when a lower step is null?

Comment: If you want to stop counting at the first null column, use `elseif` instead of `if`.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. Consider revising your schema- although I'm puzzled why no one's mentioned this already

Comment: @Strawberry if it works it ain't stupid haha! This is just a scenario based question, thus I am guessing people are attempting to solve this problem and not how they would script the entire question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue might be that msyqli_fetch_array() will only set values to `null` if their actual database value is `NULL`. From the PHP manual:

```
Note: This function sets NULL fields to the PHP NULL value.
```

So `$fetch` will contain the first matching row to your query, and `$fetch['step_5']` will only be null if it's NULL in the database. Maybe they're empty strings?

As per Barmar's comment, maybe trying using empty() instead of is_null().

Comment: You should explain how to do it better, e.g. use `if (!empty($fetch['step_5']))`

Comment: Thank you for that feedback!

Comment: Hmm, are the actual values in the database NULL?